# JQuery click class event triggers multiple clicks

Tags: jquery

I have a number of image items with class 'more-info' that should respond to click event and load ajax content to a div, however this works find for the first time, but when I click in any other image for the second time, it triggers 2 clicks for third time it triggers 3 clicks and so on.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="test" style="display:none"></div>

<div class="image-item">
    <img class="more-info" src="/site/uploads/documents/_thumb01.jpg"  path="/site/auto/1" />
</div>
<div class="image-item">
    <img class="more-info" src="/site/uploads/documents/_thumb02.jpg" path="/site/auto/2" />
</div>
<div class="image-item">
    <img class="more-info" src="/site/uploads/documents/_thumb03.jpg" path="/site/auto/4" />
</div>
```

And ajax handdler:

```
  $(function () {  
    $('.more-info').click(function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault()

            url = $(this).attr('path');
                $('#test').load(url, function(){
                alert('loaded: '+ url)
            })
    })
});
```

Comment: put css code in  your question

Comment: Check this for different solutions for your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024389/jquery-click-event-is-firing-multiple-times-when-using-class-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are loading an entire html page again including the javascript. So for each click you will have another event handler added.

So instead of loading the entire page you could only load a specific part of the page:

```
$('#test').load(url + ' #somediv', function(){
```

See [jQuery's load example](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) in the docs.

Or you should just make sure the result of the request only contains the part you need.

One last possible solution would be to `.unbind()` the event before loading the content:

```
$(function () {  
    $('.more-info').click(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();

        // for caching the element, because it will be referenced twice
        var $elem = $(this);

        url = $elem.attr('path');

        $elem.unbind('click');
        $('#test').load(url, function() {
            // used console.log which is cleaner imho
            console.log('loaded: '+ url);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You.  The problem was reloading the js file again