# jquery multi execution for button class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fairly simple script that listens for a click event on a class this works fine on the first time it is clicked. but the problem is when an additional button is pressed it will execute the function more than once. I have read this is due to each new button press creates a new event handler but how am I suppose to resolve this?

the JQuery code I have is

```
$('.ButShare').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

This is the simplified code that I have which still displays the symptoms

Regards

Vip32

Comment: That code does not produce the error that you describe. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vngf7p1t/ You're most likely hooking up the click handler somewhere that is causing it to get bound repeatedly.

Comment: @PranavCBalan That's not gonna help him figure out what is causing the unexpected behaviour..

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery click class event triggers multiple clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130543/jquery-click-class-event-triggers-multiple-clicks)

Comment: _"this works fine on the first time it is clicked. but the problem is when an additional button is pressed it will execute the function more than once."_ Is expected result to attach `click` event to only first `.ButShare` element ?

Comment: may be it's parent also have same class

Comment: Add your HTML code if you can please.

Comment: @halfzebra thanks I found the answer in the link you posted. adding id.unbind('click'); to the end of my script seems to have the desired affect when clicking multiple triggers with the same class