# jQuery click event triggered multiple times off one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with multiple clicks being registered in jQuery when only one element has been clicked. I have read some other threads on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024389/jquery-click-event-is-firing-multiple-times-when-using-class-selector) to try and work it out but I reckon it is the code I have written. The HTML code is not valid, but that is caused by some HTML 5 and the use of YouTube embed code. Nothing that affects the click.

The jQuery, triggered on document.ready

```
function setupHorzNav(portalWidth) {
    $('.next, .prev').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
            initiateScroll(target);
            console.log("click!");
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });

    function initiateScroll(target) {
        var position = $(target).offset();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollLeft: position.left
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Example HTML

```
<nav class="prev-next">
    <a href="#countdown-wrapper" class="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#signup-wrapper" class="next">Next</a>
</nav>
```

In Firefox one click can log a "Click!" 16 times! Chrome only sees one, but both browsers have shown problems with the above code.

Have I written the code wrongly or is there a bug?

-- Some extra info ------------------------------------------

setupHorzNav is called by another function in my code. I have tested this and have confirmed it is only called once on initial load.

```
if ( portalWidth >= 1248 ) {
    wrapperWidth = newWidth * 4;
    setupHorzNav(newWidth);
}
else
{
    wrapperWidth = '100%';
}
```

There are mutiple instances of nav 'prev-next'. All target different anchors. All are within the same html page.

```
<nav class="prev-next">
    <a href="#video-wrapper" class="prev">Prev</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you post where you're calling `setupHorzNav` from and the code surrounding `<nav class="prev-next">`?

Comment: Well just a few suggestions. You don't need to use `each` in this scenario, just use: `$('.next, .prev').click(function (e) { //... });`. And you don't need to use all three of `e.stopPropagation();`, `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;`. `return false;` automatically does the `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`. Those are useful if you _only_ want to do one of them, or want to execute it sooner than `return false` because of possible problems in your code

Comment: Also, it is better to *define* your event handler function outside a loop (such as each in your case), to make sure you do not have multiple instances of the same function in memory.

Comment: @techfoobar Hmm great point, I never thought of that. At the same time, I'm not sure I've ever defined event handlers in a loop, but it makes me wonder

Comment: If the code that establishes the event handler is only executed once, then how the function is defined won't matter. If it's executed more than once, then saving a stray function is irrelevant because the code would be broken anyway.

Comment: I believe chrome also shows 16 logs but as a digit in front of the line.

Comment: Put a `console.log` right at the start of your `setupHorzNav` function and check how many times it is getting called.

Comment: @Pointy I think techfoobar's point wasn't evaluating it as "correct", but suggesting an improvement. Just as what I did. The code the OP has seems fine, just not the most efficient. If you are looping and bind an event to an element (an anonymous function), then you have multiple copies of the same function being bound - a new copy for each element. If you specify the function before the loop and use that as a reference, there's only 1 copy of the "same" function.

Comment: I have updated my answer (with a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/aRYVq/2/) as well) to a snippet that is causing a similar effect. See if that is what is happening in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `.each()` for binding event handlers. Try this instead:

```
$('.next, .prev').click(function(e){
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        initiateScroll(target);
        console.log("click!");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
});
```

**EDIT:**
I think it is the way you are attaching the event handler from within the `setupHorzNav` function that is causing it. Change it to attach it only once from say, `$(document).ready()` or something.

I have managed to get the situation of multiple event handlers by attaching the event handlers from a function that gets called from event handler. The effect is that the number of click event handlers keeps increasing geometrically with each click.

This is the code: (and the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/aRYVq/2/) demo)

```
function setupNav() {
    $('.next, .prev').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            setupNav();
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
            console.log("click!");
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
}

setupNav();
```

See how calling the `setupNav()` function from the click event handler adds multiple eventhandlers (and the `click` log message) on successive clicks

Comment: Wouldn't change/help/fix anything, this is the same as if `each` were used. `each` is just unnecessary in this situation, as you've pointed out, but wouldn't help if changed

Comment: I have used the first example code you have added. It works now. I can confirm in FF and Chrome that clicks are triggered as expected. There are no weird scroll issues now. Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Try unbinding the click event like this

```
$(this).unbind('click').click(function (e) {    
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since it is not clear from your question whether you are calling the binding function multiple times, a quick and dirty fix would be:

```
$('.next, .prev').unbind('click').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

What you are doing here is *unbinding* any previously bound event handlers for `click` and binding afresh.

Answer (score 1):

Are there no other click bindings elsewhere?

Are you loading the page with ajax?

You could also try this:

```
$('.next, .prev').click(function (e) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    initiateScroll(target);
    console.log("click!");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: There are click bindings elsewhere but on unrelated items, triggered by seperate functions. The page is not loaded via ajax.